# Unable to start JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

Got the below log while starting JBoss EAP 7 in JBoss Developer studio:

```
08:12:26,838 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990
at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:224) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:144)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:54)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:38)

    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:147)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.create(ManagementHttpServer.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:190) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more

08:12:26,843 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
08:12:26,863 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
08:12:26,845 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
08:12:26,870 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
08:12:27,009 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
08:12:27,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990

08:12:27,394 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015964: Http management interface is not enabled
08:12:27,394 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled
08:12:27,394 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started (with errors) in 3937ms - Started 127 of 186 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 56 services are passive or on-demand)
```

I tried to solve by changing ports (Web:8080 and management:9999) in the server console, still the problem exist.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is that you have another instance of JBoss running in backround. This happens for example, if you start JBoss within eclipse and eclipse crashes - after restart you are not able to start your server again due to the fact that it is still active. So check your running processes if there's still another JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding offset to the ports in standalone.xml in JBoss.

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:9}">
```

Here in this case, I have added offset as 9. You can choose any other number to get a new port which is not bound.

OR

You can also verify if there is another instance of JBoss instance running and shut it down.

Hope this helps.